# How do I add a dynamic amount of columns to a DataGridView (I want to make a time line)

Tags: c#, datagridview, datacolumn

I am making a little program in C# where the user has to select a certain date and fill in a length for three different stages (Start -, Mid - and End Stage). After receiving those data, I want the program to show a time line in the form of a DataGridView. So the total amount of columns should be the sum of those stage lengths. For now I do not have anything to do with the actual dates, I just want to have a table that shows as many columns as the amount of days selected by the user.

So I - being a bit of a newbie in C# - thought that I can maybe do it with a "for loop"

```
public static int startStage;
public static int midStage;
public static int endStage;

private DataGridView timeLine;
private DataGridViewColumn[] AllDays = new DataGridViewColumn[startStage+ midStage+ endStage];

private void createTimeLine()
{
        for (int x = 0; x < (startStage+ midStage+ endStage); x++)
        {

            AllDays[x] = new DataGridViewColumn();

            timeLine.Columns.Add(AllDays[x]);
        }

}
```

Well, this does not work because the `timeLine.Columns.Add();` wants to contain a new Column with a title and a type. I do not know what to do, and google does not give me any useful suggestions either. So I will be very very thankful if anyone can give me a solution or just some help in the right direction :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to specify the cell template for the column.

Try the following:

```
 new DataGridViewColumn() { CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() };
```

More explicitly:

```
private void createTimeLine()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < (startStage+ midStage+ endStage); x++)
    {
        AllDays[x] = new DataGridViewColumn();
        AllDays[x].CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(); // for TextBox
        timeLine.Columns.Add(AllDays[x]);
    }

}
```

This will generate blank columns with no headers.

Also you can shorten it further by generating DataGridViewTextBoxColumns:

```
private void createTimeLine()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < (startStage+ midStage+ endStage); x++)
    {
        AllDays[x] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        timeLine.Columns.Add(AllDays[x]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It is really great that when are trying to learn C#, people are offering proper help. Somehow though, I was not able to solve my problem with your answer, but the answer of Padmanaban Gokula did the trick!

Comment: However, I do like this more. I get an error that the array is out of bound. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Ah, it was my mistake, I defined the length of the array before the values for the stages were known. So that's why my array was out of bound.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out, and that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy you just need to add HeaderText and Column To Columns.Add Method....

```
    public static int startStage=10;
    public static int midStage=2;
    public static int endStage=1;
    private DataGridView timeLine= new DataGridView();

    private void createTimeLine()
    {
       for (int x = 0; x < (startStage + midStage + endStage); x++)
        {
         timeLine.Columns.Add(x.ToString(),x.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tanks a lot for your answer! It works just fine now!